# WSO API Manager hide some information of the request of BODY

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In API Manager version 3.0.0, I try to hide some information of the request, example:

The service is: `https://API/v1/client` with the method **GET**, the request is similar to:

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "nickname": "Example",
  "name": "LUIS",
  ...


  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://API/v1/client/3/settings"
     }
    } 
 }
]
```

But I have to hide the information relative to **_links**.
My idea is in **Publisher Page -> Runtime Configurations add a sequence in Message Mediation in the Request**.

Is possible to do or not?

**Edit**

Answer to **Vithursa M**, I don't know what was a error but after to restart my PC the policy add whit any problem. When and Try Out send this error:

[image: Error in Devportal page]

Also in terminal sends:

```
ERROR - RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:165) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:168) [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:121) [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:152) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate_aroundBody0(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:72) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:57) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleResponse_aroundBody4(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:127) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleResponse(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:115) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:364) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:149) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:58) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:325) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:578) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:195) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v38.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:284) [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v38.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2052) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    ... 27 more
[2020-02-14 09:49:24,217] ERROR - SequenceMediator Error while building message. Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:432) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:214) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:121) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:152) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate_aroundBody0(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:72) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:57) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleResponse_aroundBody4(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:127) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleResponse(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:115) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:364) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:149) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:58) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:325) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:578) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:195) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v38.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:284) [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v38.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:165) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:168) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    ... 22 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2052) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:165) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:168) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    ... 22 more
[2020-02-14 09:49:24,220] ERROR - admin--Alquimia2 Error while building message. Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:432) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:214) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:121) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:152) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate_aroundBody0(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:72) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:57) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleResponse_aroundBody4(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:127) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleResponse(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:115) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.5.349.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:364) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:149) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:58) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:325) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:578) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:195) [synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:2.1.7-wso2v131]
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v38.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:284) [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v38.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:165) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:168) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    ... 22 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '[' (code 91) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2052) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566) ~[axiom_1.2.11.wso2v16.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:165) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:168) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v131.jar:?]
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: You do not need to send "_links" parameter to back-end? If so, yes you can use custom mediation policy.

Comment: One solution is change the parameter "_links" in back-end but exists some many services. And how could do a mediation policy?

Answer (score 1):

If your input payload is like:

```
{
   "element": [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "nickname": "Example",
       "name": "LUIS",
       "_links": {
         "self": {
         "href": "https://API/v1/client/3/settings"
         }
       } 
     }
   ]
}
```

You can use following mediation policy to remove the "_links" attribute from the payload, using script mediator.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="sampleSeq">
    <script language="js"><![CDATA[
        var payload = mc.getPayloadJSON();
        var elements = payload.element;
        for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++){
          if (elements[i].hasOwnProperty("_links")) {
              delete elements[i]["_links"];
          }
        }        
        mc.setPayloadJSON(payload);
    ]]></script>
    <send/>
</sequence>
```

Comment: When add the script mediator, API Manager don't loading and response: 
`ApisApiServiceImpl Error while getting location header for created mediation policy SCRIPT.xml
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 118`

Comment: Seems like there is illegal characters in the constructed registry path, can you send the complete error trace?